# How to deploy the contract based on user input and make them contract owner?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, javascript

I have seen a website dappbuilder.org they provide a launchpad platform on which user input the details like name of token supply and click on create and after approving the transaction contracts get created and user will become the owner. also while approving the transaction dappbuilder also adds it's own fees, but all I want to know is what login they are using.

Answer (score 1):

They're using [metamask](https://metamask.io/) for interacting with Web3 and they're using create2 opcode of solidity to create smart contracts from one smart contract similar to that of gnosis. But A2A it's a basic thing of using metamask for web3 Logins.

So to achieve same results, the following could be helpful,
https://medium.com/@PhABC/here-are-a-few-things-you-can-do-with-create2-that-create-cant-permit-f9e8809e6efd

https://itnext.io/build-your-first-solidity-dapp-with-web3-js-and-metamask-b18d63196bb5